# WPF How to copy selected items from itemsbound listbox to another

Tags: wpf, listbox, copy

All examples I find are for a non itemsbound WPF listbox: I need to copy items from listbox A (bound to a collection A), to another listbox B (bound to a collection B of the same type).

If I am correct I need to copy from collection A to collection B and then refresh the listbox.

How do I get the indexes of the selected items?

Or is there another way to accomplish this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add IsSelected property to your collection-Items, and change ListboxItemTemplate to bind ListboxItem IsSelected property to your IsSelected property. and then copy from collection A to collection B.

with this approach you don't need to remember selected-indexes, all will be done by binding.

Answer (score 0):

Make ColectionA and CollectionB into `ObservableCollection<Item>`. That way the ListBox controls that they are bound to will automatically update when items are added / removed.

To do the actual copy from one collection to another you need something like this.

```
CollectionB.Clear()
foreach(var item in CollectionA.Where(i => ...))
    CollectionB.Add(item);
```